# How to use autocomplete angular material with dynamic data source (SQL)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

i wasn't managed to get it working even with the mat-table option also
ive tryed to look on youtube and found only hard coded autocomplete
and i added some related code parts thanks for the help

https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x6fkf2?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from 'src/app/services/user.model';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/services/user.service';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-companyinteraction',
  templateUrl: './companyinteraction.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./companyinteraction.component.css']
})
export class CompanyinteractionComponent implements OnInit {


  public companies:User[];

  
  constructor(private prodService:UserService,private fb: FormBuilder) { }
    


  ngOnInit() {
    const ob = this.prodService.getUsers();
    ob.subscribe(users => {
      this.companies = users;
      console.log(this.companies);
      console.log('test123 from CompanyInteraction component.ts'); 


      
    });

  }

}
```

```html
<div id="firstdiv">
    <h1>Corporation Interaction</h1>
  </div>



  <div class="divTable" style="width: 100%;" >
      <div class="divTableBody">
      <div class="divTableRow">




      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;
          <h4>Select Company</h4>
          <mat-form-field class="valuePicker">
            <mat-label>Select Company</mat-label>
            <mat-select>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let p of companies" [value]="p.CompanyName">
                  {{p.CompanyName}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
           </mat-form-field>
      </div>


      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;
          <h4>Select Subject</h4>
          <mat-form-field class="valuePicker">
              <mat-label>Select Subject</mat-label>
              <mat-select>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let p of companies" [value]="p.CompanyName">
                    {{p.CompanyName}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
             </mat-form-field>
      </div>


      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;
          <h4>Select Date</h4>
          <mat-form-field class="valuePicker" >
              <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
              <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
              <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
      </div>


      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;
          <h4>Follow Up</h4>
          <mat-form-field class="valuePicker">
              <mat-label>Follow Up</mat-label>
              <mat-select>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let p of companies" [value]="p.CompanyName">
                    {{p.CompanyName}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
             </mat-form-field>

      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>


    <form class="example-form">

        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input matInput #message maxlength="256" placeholder="Insert Details" rows='3'>
          <mat-hint align="start"><strong>Click the button to update details</strong> </mat-hint>
          <mat-hint align="end">{{message.value.length}} / 256</mat-hint>
       </mat-form-field>
        <button id="btn" mat-raised-button color="primary">Send to database</button>
      </form>


      <form class="example-form">

        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input matInput #message maxlength="256" placeholder="Insert New Subject" rows='4'>
          <mat-hint align="start"><strong>Click the button to update details</strong> </mat-hint>
          <mat-hint align="end">{{message.value.length}} / 256</mat-hint>
        </mat-form-field>
        <button id="btn" mat-raised-button color="primary">Send to database</button>
      </form>
```

```js
export class User {
    constructor(
    CompanyName:string,
    CompanyNumber?:Int32Array,
    BankAccountNumber?:string,
    Contact1?:string,
    Phone1?:Int32Array,
    Email1?:string,
    Contact2?:string,
    Phone2?:Int32Array,
    Email2?:string){}
}
```

Comment: do you have an api to filter autocomplete data?

Comment: i have regular web api i need to create other one only for that auto complete?

Comment: how would you filter data else if you have 2k results say you want to autocomplete 10 results only

Comment: no i only want to autocomplete only CompanyName and i have max 10-20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can mark the api output to a variable no need for subscribe

```js
options$: Observable<string[]>;
constructor(private service: UserService){
  this.options$ = this.service.getUsers();
}
```

Then in your template bind the observable note that async pipe is used for options

```html
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options$ | async" [value]="option">
        {{option.CompanyName}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Here is the StackBlitz for the demo. Please note I have simulated the api call in user.service giving it a 5 second delay so you can check what would happen in real world.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3heeda

Hope this helps

Comment: that should be in your code, might be some declarations you are missing

Comment: does the above snippet solve your original question?

Comment: did you declare this `options$: Observable<string[]>;`

Comment: check your import compare from stackblitz

Comment: constructor(
    private prodService:UserService,
    options$: Observable<string[]>
    ) { };

Comment: what are u trying to do?